# Error while reading a file from memory in Quartus prime

Tags: verilog, fpga, quartus

I am trying to read a .txt file, stored in my computer in Quartus Prime using the "$readmemh" function, but it doesn't seem to work. I am getting an error like.

```
Error (10054): Verilog HDL File I/O error at scratch.v(8): can't open Verilog Design File "img_process_data_text.txt".
```

Code:

```
module scratch(clk,addr,out);

input clk;
input[1:0] addr;
output reg out;
reg [3:0] mem [3:0];
initial 
$readmemh("img_process_data_text.txt",mem);
always @ (posedge clk)
out<=mem[addr];
 endmodule
```

I have also tried it with the full path directory of img_process_data_txt, but it had the same error.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Either the text file is not in the directory or it is a permission issue. If your are in Linux try:

```
ls -la <directory_where_is_the_txt_file>
```

And look at the ownership.

Comment: m4j0rt0m. Thanks for the reply.. But actually i have used the same file(in .hex) to initialise a ROM megafunction and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates you have listed this as an HDL design file. It should not be listed.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, what should I do then in order to read a file using readmemh in quartus?

Comment: The .txt file needs to be in the directory where you execute quartus from, or you need to use the complete path in the readmem command.

Comment: Well I tried using full path to it but still it didn't work. Can u mention the other way round of copying the file in quartus.?  I mean the exact location where i should put it

Answer (score -1):

Open Windows Folder Options and Make sure the file extension is not hidden.

The extension name of the file you have is probably filename.txt.txt

You must fix it with filename.txt